# Unable to specify initial size of vector

Tags: c++, vector, size, member

I have a class called ChessBoard and one of the member variables is

```
std::vector<ChessPiece *> pieces(16);
```

This is giving me an "expected a type specifier" error. The default constructor of ChessPiece is private. However, if I write the same statement inside a function it works perfectly (i.e. the initial size of pieces is 16). Why is it reporting an error when I try to specify initial size of a member variable? Thanks!

SSCCE:

```
class ChessPiece {

    ChessPiece();

public:
    ChessPiece(int value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};

class ChessBoard {

    ChessBoard();
    std::vector<ChessPiece *> pieces(16); // Error: expected a type specifier

public:
    ChessBoard(int value) { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

    std::vector<ChessPiece *> pieces(16);
    std::cout << pieces.size() << std::endl; // prints 16
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't call a method on a member variable inside your class declaration.

In your cpp file you could do something like:

```
ChessBoard::ChessBoard() { pieces.resize(16); }
```

or:

```
ChessBoard::ChessBoard(): pieces(16) {}
```

The second one calls the vector constructor that takes a size argument. Or you can directly do it in your .h file:

```
class ChessBoard {
    ChessBoard(): pieces(16) {} // version 1
    ChessBoard(): pieces() { pieces.resize(16); }  // version 2

private:
    std::vector<ChessPiece *> pieces;
};
```

Comment: Your first `ChessBoard` constructor looks wrong. Maybe you mean `ChessBoard(): pieces(16) {}`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Whoops, fixed. Thank you

Comment: I may be wrong but wouldn't pieces.resize(16) throw an error since the default constructor is inaccessible?

Comment: @IzaanSiddiqi: How is it inaccessible?

Comment: I made it private to prevent others (even though that's just me) from using it.

Comment: @IzaanSiddiqi Try it out. But no, it wouldn't be a problem because it does not cause any default constructor calls.

Comment: I did but I got `1>chess_board.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cp::ChessPiece::ChessPiece(void)" (??0ChessPiece@cp@@QAE@XZ)`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake somewhere else and it's working now. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 12):

The required syntax for in-place initialization of data members does not allow the `()` initialization syntax common with non-members. You can use this syntax instead:

```
std::vector<ChessPiece*> pieces = std::vector<ChessPiece*>(16);
```